Ultralytics installation successful, but cant execute a yolo predict
I just installed ultralytics using the anaconda prompt and pip following the quickstart guide. When I tried to run the test code yolo predict model=yolov8n.pt imgsz=640 conf=0.25. Aside from a few version warnings, this appears.
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.196  Python-3.11.5 torch-2.4.0+cu118 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti, 12288MiB)
Error.  nthreads cannot be larger than environment variable "NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS" (8)YOLOv8n summary (fused): 168 layers, 3151904 parameters, 0 gradients, 8.7 GFLOPs

And I wont get any results
Also installed pytorch usccesfully using pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118 because i'll need the gpu.
I havent found a way to succesfully modify "NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS" from its default value nor have I found much related to nthreads.

Ok, i solved it by just uninstalling and reinstalling ultralytics and anything related to pytorch.
pip uninstall ultralytics torch torchvision torchaudio
pip install ultralytics
pip install pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118

In my case it was the CUDA 11.8 version
